# OpenShift 4.11.9 (UPI) - The master node cannot finish the installation ("config/master", "get error EOF")

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, fedora, coreos-ignition

> ignition[849]: GET error: Get "https://api-int.lab.ocp.lan:22623/config/master": EOF

I am getting this after rhcos install on bare metal virtual machine running on esxi 6.0.0

The guide i am using:
https://github.com/ryanhay/ocp4-metal-install

ocp-svc - using fedora server instead of centos, because of deprecation.

rhcos-live.x86_64.iso version 4.11.9

Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-36-1.5.iso (latest, downloaded yesterday)

Everything is followed from the guide, so i think that could be a bug or something changed in the newer versions.

Happen's after successful install of rhcos.raw.gz from RHCOS and rebooting the machine.
(ex.: sudo coreos-installer install /dev/sda -u http://192.168.22.1:8080/ocp4/rhcos -I http://192.168.22.1:8080/ocp4/master.ign --insecure --insecure-ignition)

Thanks!

Comment: If you're working with OpenShift, Red Hat support might be a more useful source of information (or if you're using OKD, there are some suggestions [here](https://www.okd.io/help/) on where to get help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this situation was the internet access. Following the guide from the github repo above, you will need also to allow traffic to be forwarded from lan to wan. That's why i was having get errors.